# Find different records between two files using Unix Commands

Tags: shell, unix

I have two files with shown records. How can I get the different records using Shell script/Unix Command. I don't want the common records from the both the files.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you attempted to solve the problem?/  Have anywhere you could think of to start?

Comment: Given the layout of these files, I'd say using a database might be a good idea.  If anything, it'll give you considerably more flexibility in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been nice to be able to copy and paste the input file text. Nevertheless:

```
comm -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | sed 's/^\t//'
```

or

```
awk '
    {count[$0]++} 
    END {for (line in count) if (count[line] == 1) print line}
' file1 file2
```

Comment: Explanations of these would be helpful to future searchers, rather than just giving teh codez.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
grep -vf File1 File2
grep -vf File2 File1
```

Thanks for correction @jm666, this is nicer

Comment: you  can join the arguments, only the `f` must be last. like `grep -vf file1 file2`